# Interpreting stata output of regression with multiple fixed effects

Tags: stata, fixed-effects-model

I am running a regression of a variables $Y$ on $firm plant$ and $firm \times time$ fixed effects. There are no independent variables in the regression except for the fixed effects.

Here is the stata command I am using:

```
reghdfe Y, absorb(firm_plant time_firm)
```

The output I am getting is the following:

[image]

Now I have some questions on the output.

What exactly does the $F(190040,3433397)$ statistic on the absorbed tests for? What about the standard $F(0,3433397)$ statistic?

Shall I care about the within R-Square?

Edit: after some comments below some clarifications:

- `reghdfe` is a stata command that runs linear and instrumental-variable regressions with many levels of fixed effects, by implementing the estimator of Correia (2015).More info [here](http://scorreia.com/software/reghdfe/quickstart.html).
- Also, absorb just indicates the fixed effects of the regression. On this case firm_plant and time_firm.

Comment: What is reghdfe? What is absorb? Why do you have an interaction without both main effects?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I asked the OP to clarify what some words meant and that has not been done.

Comment: Okay, my apologies. reghdfe is a stata command that runs linear and instrumental-variable regressions with many levels of fixed effects, by implementing the estimator of Correia (2015).More info here: http://scorreia.com/software/reghdfe/quickstart.html

Also, absorb just indicates the fixed effects of the regression. On this case firm_plant and time_firm.

Comment: OK, I'll re-open, but please put that explanation in your question, not just a comment.

Comment: 1000 views on this question and no answer ...